# flask's application context and global connection

Tags: python, flask, global

I need to create a connection pool to database which can be reused by requests in Flask. The documentation(`0.11.x`) suggests to use `g`, the application context to store the database connections.

The issue is application context is created and destroyed before and after each request. Thus, there is no limit on the number of connection being created and no connection is getting reused. The code I am using is:

```
def get_some_connection():
    if not hasattr(g, 'some_connection'):
        logger.info('creating connection')
        g.some_connection = SomeConnection()
    return g.some_connection
```

and to close the connection

```
@app.teardown_appcontext
def destroy_some_connection(error):
    logger.info('destroying some connection')
    g.some_connection.close()
```

Is this intentional, that is, flask want to create a fresh connection everytime, or there is some issue with the use of application context in my code. Also, if its intentional is there a workaround to have the connection global. I see, some of the old extensions keep the connection in `app['extension']` itself.

Answer (score 3):

No, you'll have to have some kind of global connection pool. `g` lets you share state across one request, so between various templates and functions called while handling one request, without having to pass that 'global' state around, but it is not meant to be a replacement for module-global variables (which have the same lifetime as the module).

You can certainly set the database connection onto `g` to ensure all of your request code uses just the one connection, but you are still free to draw the connection from a (module) global pool.

I recommend you create connections *per thread* and pool these. You can either build this from scratch (use a `threading.local` object perhaps), or you can use a project like SQLAlchemy which comes with *excellent* connection pool implementations. This is basically what the [Flask-SQLAlchemy extension](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/) does.

Comment: Then what is the difference between request and application context.

Comment: @SiddharthGupta: the app context lives longer; it is there before the request context is created and remains until just after the response has been set out.